# How to analyze repeated measures data with small sample size, but thousands of observations per subject

Tags: r, mixed-model, panel-data

I'd like some general help figuring out which statistical approaches might be useful for my current situation. I'm working with:

- A sample of 7 subjects; `id`
- A 'time' variable (measured in seconds [0...~15000]) consisting of about 15,000 observations per subject; `time`
- A continuous dependent variable: tissue pH; `pH`
- One factor variable: levels = Before, During, and After an intervention occurs `intervention`

I'm not providing the data because of the size of the dataset, and what I really want is help with the statistical aspect, rather than the programming aspect.

I would like to be able to evaluate whether or not the `intervention` variable is associated with changes `pH` over time, accounting for within-subject correlation.

I attempted to fit a mixed model using R's `lme4` package, which looked like:

```
# First model:
model1 <- lmer(pH ~ 1 + time*intervention + (1 + time | id), data = mydata)
# Did not converge

# Removed the interaction variable to see if that was the issue:
model2 <- lmer(pH ~ 1 + time + (1 + time | id), data = mydata)
# Still would not converge
```

So I'm wondering what the issue might be. Is it a sample size issue? Is it the number of observations? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way? I've searched this website and several books on longitudinal analysis and multilevel analysis over multiple weeks, and have yet to find someone with a similar situation. I would greatly appreciate *any* suggestions anyone has to offer.

**Update:**
Thanks for your suggestion. I ran the models per your suggestion:

```
# Without time as a fixed effect
m0 <- lmer(pH ~ 1 + (1|id), mydata)
# Results:
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: pH ~ 1 + (1 | id)
   Data: mydata
REML criterion at convergence: 813300.3
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.2057  
 Residual             0.3497  
Number of obs: 1103971, groups:  ID, 7
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
      7.367 

# With time as a fixed effect:
m0 <- lmer(pH ~ 1 + Time + (1|id), mydata)

# Results:
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: pH ~ 1 + time + (1 | ID)
   Data: mydata
REML criterion at convergence: -677647.3
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.2139  
 Residual             0.1780  
Number of obs: 1103971, groups:  ID, 7
Fixed Effects:
 (Intercept)     time
   6.859e+00     6.442e-06  
fit warnings:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

So yes, it appears that both of your suggested simpler models will converge. How should I move forward if I would like to add some covariates and an interaction term? Thanks again.

Comment: Does an even simpler model converge, such as `m0 <- lmer(pH ~ 1 + (1|id), mydata`? If that converges, then add the fixed effect of time. My advice with data of this sort is to start simple and build from there. Please update your question when you do this bottom up approach and what works and what doesn't.

Comment: When you say it doesn't converge what is the actual message ? Does this model converge ?  
`pH ~ time*intervention + (1 | id)`